# Yii2 ActiveQuery "Where" not working

Tags: php, yii2

I'm learning Yii2 framework and PHP, and I can't find solution to my problem.

I have AR Model Project with *many-to-many* relation:

```
    public function getUsers() {
    return $this->hasMany(UserAR::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])
        ->viaTable('user_project', ['project_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

I want to retrieve all projects with User of given ID, And reverse - all projects without this user. So far I tried it this way:

```
   $uid =  Yii::$app->user->id;
   $projects = Project::find()->all();
   foreach($projects as $p){
        $found = $p->getUsers()->where(['id'=>$uid])->all();
        echo"<pre>"; var_dump($found);
   }
```

but it returns `NULL` for every iteration,
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if you change the 4th line, for testing, to just `$found = $p->getUsers()` is it still showing null?
I think it has a problem with getUsers() function, on relation.

Comment: Nope, it returns object(yii\db\ActiveQuery)#110 (27)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, Somehow I tested from Administrative account which wasn't attached to any of my projects - that's why it returned `null` - when I changed `$uid` to correct Value, It worked as I desired. Thanks Chainarong Tangsurakit for pointing me in right direction.

Comment: Seeing people using Yii more make me feel glad :D